# Yarn workspaces shared dependencies

Tags: dependencies, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, peer-dependencies

I'm trying to build a project that uses yarn workspaces.
And here's what I want to accomplish in my setup:

```
> root
  > packages
    > client
        package.json
          - graphql
    > server
        package.json
          - graphql
  package.json
    - graphql
```

I installed graphql in my root `package.json` because `graphql-codegen` needs it to be there (otherwise it will give me wall of unmet dependency warnings!).

AFAIK, if I want to install the same exact dependency in more than 1 workspace, I need to specify it inside `peerDependency`, so I did. I tried to peer install `graphql` inside server `package.json`, but then yarn gave me this warning below and install `graphql` in `dependencies` instead.

```sh
"graphql" is already in "dependencies". Please remove existing entry first before adding it to "peerDependencies".
```

Am I missing something?